# Problema con emmet a la hora de crear listas y enlaces

Tags: css, html5, emmet

tengo el siguiente problema. al usar esta abreviatura de emmet, nav>ul>li*5>a
me sale el siguiente código:
[image: Código incómodo]

Como puedo hacer para hacer que los enlaces esten dentro de cada li pero que no salte a cada linea. espero que me hallan entendido.
Gracias por sus respuestas,

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A modo de comentario personal te diré que es mejor que te acostumbres a una línea por elemento, el código se entiende y se ve mejor para todos. Quizás a ti ahora no te guste pero llegara el momento donde veras que lo recomendable es tener el código como Emmet te lo está dando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a que salgan de esta manera:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

No es así.

De ser así, debe haber algo en las configuraciones del Emmet que te permita hacer eso. O simplemente puedes añadir primero hasta las listas. Y mientras mantienes presionado la tecla "alt" , puedes seleccionar las 4 etiquetas li y añadir las etiquetas a en cada una de ellas al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Hola amigos, gracias por darse su tiempo para comentar. Efectivamente zaraterdz asi desplegaba emmet mi lista antes, por algun motivo se desconfiguró, pero gracias al codigo de otro usuario en ingles pude dejarlo como estaba, que para mi es mas ordenado y legible.

Comment: De nada Jorge, échale!